# Can't get information about username and password from MySQL when doing log in page

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I got a assignment to do log in and register page using ajax, php and jQuery. The problem is that when register page passes the information to my MySQL database witch name is users and it includes username, password, fname, lname and email fields, I can't get logged in with the same information.

My code looks like this:

```
<?php
        include_once('db.php');

    $username = mysql_real_escape_string ($_POST["username"]);
    $password = mysql_real_escape_string (md5($_POST["password"]));

    if(empty($username) || empty($password))
        echo "Username and Password are mandatory to Login";
    else
    {
    $sql = "SELECT count(*) FROM users WHERE(
            username = '$username'
        AND
            password = '$password')";


        $res = mysql_query($sql);
        $row = mysql_fetch_array($res);

        if($row[0] > 0)
            echo "Login Successful";
        else
            echo "Failed to Login. Please check your Username and Password and try again";
    }
?>
```

and every time I try to log in with the same information that is passed in MySQL I get the "Failed to Login" message. Maybe it's some kind of problem with the server? Can it be? Because code should be fine.

I will include my code for log in page too, maybe it helps:

```
<html>
<head><title>Login Page</title></head>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/jquery-2.0.3.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="script/script.js"></script>

<form id="loginForm" action="login.php" method="POST">
Username: <input type="text" name="username" id="username"/><br/>
Password: <input type="password" name="password" id="password"/><br/>
<button id="submit">Login</button>
</form> 


<div id="ackk"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

script.js

```
$("button#submit").click( function() {

  if( $("#username").val() == "" || $("#password").val() == "" )
    $("#ackk").html("Please enter both username and password");
  else
    $.post( $("#loginForm").attr("action"),
            $("#loginForm :input").serializeArray(),
            function(data) {
              $("#ackk").html(data);
            });

    $("#loginForm").submit( function() {
       return false;    
    });

});
```

**SOLUTION:** Funny thing that posting this problem I thought about one thing, md5 encryption uses 32 characters and when I created a SQL database I selected just 30 chars for password space, I guess that happens when you are new in programming things you never thought you gonna try to program. Although thank you for your fast answers especially @popnoodles I will try to implement that.

Comment: Please don't use the click of a button to submit a form. There is more than one way to submit a form, and clicking a button is not the option I usually use for logging in. `$("#loginForm").on('submit', function(e){ e.preventDefault(); /* your $.post  */ });`

Comment: use PDO instead of mysql_*.

Comment: Funny thing that posting this problem I thought about one thing, md5 encryption uses 32 characters and when I created a SQL database I selected just 30 chars for password space, I guess that happens when you are new in programming things you never thought you gonna try to program. Although thank you for your fast answers especially @popnoodles I will try to implement that.

Comment: Have you validated that your DB connection is functioning? I'm assuming that db.php maintains your connection?